# Passing arbitrary data to a function without void pointers

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, void-pointers

I am working with an abstract base class implementing a set of system tests.  In simplified form, the class declaration is:

```
class Test_Class
{
    Test_Class();
    ~Test_Class();

    Run_Test(void * param_set = NULL) = 0;
}
```

The base class requires the implementation of the Run_Test function which allows a user to pass in an arbitrary data structure as a void pointer and cast it to the appropriate type inside the body of Run_Test in a child class, in order to allow different tests to use different data structures, e.g. a float in one test vs a list of ints in another.

This is cumbersome and seems like an incredibly C-like way of doing things.  Is there a better way of using inheritance or other language utilities?

Note: Due to customer constraints, this program is not allowed access to the STL or the Boost libraries.

Comment: [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/any.html) was made for exactly this sort of task.

Comment: Agreed with respect to boost::any, unfortunately neither the boost libraries nor STL are available on our project.  Updated the question to reflect that fact.

Comment: @DeadMG what about embedded, system-on-chip customers? My customers dont allow me to use even c++

Comment: In point of fact, this is for an embedded system. Thanks for the help, all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  User doesn't pass in an *arbitary* data structure but can *make* an arbitrary data structure by extending your base class.

```
class Test_Class {
    Run_Test(const Config& config);
};
```

client code:

```
class MyConfig : public Config {
    //...
};
```

Another option is templates.  You can accomplish many common tasks with either, I'm not sure which is ideal in this situation so I'll leave it to other answers or to you to research that if you go this route.

Comment: You are suggesting Config as a base class for parameter passing which can be extended for specific tests?

Comment: Yes.  The client can then handle appropriately, but I will tell you if your client has to use dynamic_cast to retrieve the derived Config it's already designed wrong.  Sounds like you want the client to submit an entire test.  You can give Config a method like bool doTest() or make it a functor, or use an approach like @DeadMG's answer.  If you still need something more general, then redesign Test_Class so it gives the client the data it needs to run the test, instead of taking very general data it doesn't know what to do with from the client.

Comment: Fair point.  The degree of casting has made me uncomfortable from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a set of tests, use `std::vector<std::function<void()>> tests;` and then you can simply `tests.push_back([=] { do_test(the_args, I_captured, from_local, scope); });`.

You can do similar tricks with `std::bind` if your compiler doesn't support lambdas.

There's no need for you, the end-user, to write your own generic function interface. It already has been done.

Edit: Yes, you're going to end up with some C-style garbage if you do not A) re-implement the wheels provided by Boost or the STL or B) use the existing wheels provided by Boost or STL. There is no magical third choice between "Write own good code" or "Use other people's good code" which still results in good code.

Comment: An excellent point.  We are unable to use the STL on this project, but otherwise I agree.  And am updating my question to make that restriction clear.

Answer (score 0):

I dont remember is it possible/how to make argument detection for function inside class so maybe this will do:

```
class Test_Class {

public:
  template <typename T>
  void Run_Test(T p) { 

  }
};

template <class T>
void tester(Test_Class t, T p) {
t.Run_Test<T>(p);
}

int main() {
  Test_Class p;
  int a = 5;

  tester(p, a);
}
```